# Netbook Remix 10.04 to 10.10 upgrade using alternate iso

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-netbook

I'm using Netbook Remix 10.04 now. I'm having the 10.10 alternate iso with me. If I use that iso to upgrade, will I lose my netbook version? I've seen in some forums that the upgrade resulted in a change from netbook version to desktop version.

**Updated on 15/12/2010**

I upgraded the OS from 10.04 to 10.10. But I'm getting an error like this after restart:

> modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory

I searched in the forums and got a solution like this:

> Open Terminal
>
> gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
>
> change the line MODULES=most to MODULES=dep
>
> Then use Synaptic (System>Administration>Synaptic Package Manager) to reinstall initramfs-tools.

I'll be definitely trying this later.

After that when the system tries to login, my screen starts flashing with just the ubuntu netbook desktop wallpaper on the screen. No other options will be available. It will be flashing continuosly. If I press the power button then one window comes up with options like Shut down, Restart, Hibernate etc. And the screen won't stop flashing either.

I've uploaded a 1 min video. Please go through it as it will give you a clear idea of the error which I'm facing now [Video Link Here](http://www.twitvid.com/8UUW4)

Answer (score 1):

Solved both the issues.

I edited initramfs.conf for solving the first one and changed the default session to ubuntu-desktop in System -> Administration -> Login Window for solving the second one.

Comment: Please mark your question answered then.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: By accepting your own answer as the best answer; there should be a green accept link/icon on the left hand side of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really confirm, but I don't think normal version would upgrade to netbook edition. You should upgrade over the internet, then you can be sure the packages will be right.